# change checkbox value vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I  need to change the checkbox value, Instead of `true` to be `1`
and instead of `false` to be `0`.

Here's my code **:**

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="flexCheckDefault"
                        v-model="discount.has_limit_times_use">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        Limit number of times this discount can be used in total
      </label>
</div>
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work. Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, it is documented in Vue 3 Form input bindings.

string value:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="discount.has_limit_times_use" true-value="1" false-value="0">
```

number value:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="discount.has_limit_times_use" :true-value="1" :false-value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

***Observation:*** As you are having `v-model` attribute in your input element. Then you can achieve the checkbox value binding via `v-model` itself.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    discount: {
        has_limit_times_use: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getVal() {
      console.log(this.discount.has_limit_times_use)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" :true-value="1" :false-value="0" v-model="discount.has_limit_times_use" @change="getVal">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you , i did a similar answer as you